# Android ListPreference default value not working

Tags: android

This is my code

```
 <ListPreference 
         android:key="yearlength"
         android:title="Year Length"
         android:entries="@array/years"
         android:entryValues="@array/yearsvalues"
         android:summary="%s"
         android:defaultValue="365.256363004"/>  

      <string-array name="years">
        <item>Mean sidereal solar year(365.256363004)</item>
        <item>Mean tropical solar year(365.24219)</item>
        <item>Savana year(360)</item>
        <item>Thithi year(354)</item>
        <item>Nakshatra year(324)</item>
        <item>Normal solar year(365.2425)</item>
       </string-array>   

       <string-array name="yearsvalues">
        <item>365.256363004</item>
        <item>365.24219</item>
        <item>360</item>
        <item>354</item>
        <item>324</item>
        <item>365.2425</item>
       </string-array>
```

I am new to andorid.The default value is not showing. 
But when i set `andorid:defaultValue="360"` its working.plz help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should use string reference.

```
<string name="default>365.256363004</string>
```

and use

```
<ListPreference 
         android:key="yearlength"
         android:title="Year Length"
         android:entries="@array/years"
         android:entryValues="@array/yearsvalues"
         android:summary="%s"
         android:defaultValue="@string/default"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<ListPreference 
         android:key="yearlength"
         android:title="Year Length"
         android:entries="@array/years"
         android:entryValues="@array/yearsvalues"
         android:summary="%s"
         android:defaultValue="365.256363004"/>
```

Dont fotget to Uninstall or clear application data and reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

The default value **inf** is parsed as a **float**, converted to a String, and then stored as the Preference default value.

Add

```
android:defaultValue="inf"
```

More Details  [Beware of Preference Default Values in XML](https://room-15.github.io/blog/2015/03/30/beware-of-preference-default-values-in-xml/)